# Staying with relatives in UAE for one night — appropriate visa?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, uae

I hold German citizenship, and am traveling from Germany to India. I'd like to visit relatives in the United Arab Emirates, which would work out nicely with my itinerary, but I'd stay over night in Abu Dhabi.

Is a transit visa sufficient here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**None**! You do not need any visa to go to UAE for 1 day.  You get 90 days on arrival as a German citizen.

[UAE Visa Information](https://www.emirates.com/de/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/)

You're probably providing incorrect input to Timatic. To me [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/de/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=DE&NV=Germany&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=AE&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=42accde487b49d28c2462563b970d117fd52c2) says this for your itinerary.

> **Transit - United Arab Emirates (AE)**
>
> **Visa**
>
> Visa required.
>
> **Visa Exemptions:**
>
> Nationals of Germany with a normal passport for a maximum stay of 90 days.

Comment: Hmm, Timatic says "Passengers may obtain a transit visa on arrival in Abu Dhabi International Airport (AUH) Terminal 3. Maximum stay of 96 hours."

Comment: Got a reference link?

Comment: No direct link, because it's a form result. https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/ and entering the full itinerary (TXL-AMM-AUH-DEL) gives me this result, leaving out DEL gives me "no visa required".

Comment: That site also says *Visa is not required for United Arab Emirates. Maximum stay of 90 days.*.

Comment: Ah, it depends on whether there is a connecting flight. So, a bug in Timatic. Thanks!